# How to customize a folder programatically on Windows 7

Tags: winapi

Windows 7 offers the possibility to customize folder icons and pictures by right clicking on the folder, choosing the "Properties" command and then the "Customize" tab, as explained for example [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/63359/how-to-customize-folder-backgrounds-and-icons-in-windows-explorer/).

Can this be done programatically ?

Comment: SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762199(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `desktop.ini` file programmatically. The file is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You could, for instance, rename the folder in an internationalization scenario (e.g. a folder named "users" could me displayed to the user as *utilisateurs* on a French OS, or *Benutzer* on a German OS), by creating a file with the following contents:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@C:\foo\bar.dll,-100
```

which would take the name of the folder in the `bar.dll` string resource ID 100.